# While inside a while is crashing the C program

Tags: c, string, while-loop

Here is my C program, This will open the file called test_fil.txt and will finally print MUX values present in the file. Here is the information inside my test_fil.txt. But the program is crashing when i rund this. It would be great if someone solves this. Thanks in advance.

```
`BO_ 377 FC_DM_MISC: 8 FC
 SG_ DATA3         m11 : 31|8@0+ (1,0) [0|0] ""  DM
 SG_ DATA4         m8  : 39|8@0+ (1,0) [0|0] ""  DM
 SG_ DATA3         m8  : 31|8@0+ (1,0) [0|0] ""  DM
 SG_ DATA2         m8  : 23|8@0+ (1,0) [0|0] ""  DM`
BA_ "GenMsgSendType" BO_ 356 0;
BA_ "GenMsgCycleTime" BO_ 356 100;
BA_ "GenMsgSendType" BO_ 358 0;
```

And here is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   char a[128];
   char *t;

   FILE *fPtr;
   fPtr = fopen("test_fil.txt","r");
   long MUX;
   while(1)
   {
     if(feof(fPtr))
     break;
     fgets(a,128,fPtr);
     while(strstr(a,"SG_")!=NULL)
     {
       t = strtok(a," ");
       t = strtok(NULL," ");
       t = strtok(NULL," ");
       printf("print the mux values %s\n",t);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `fgets(a.128,fPtr);`? Please show real code.

Comment: `while(strstr(a,"SG_")!=NULL)` That should be `if`. Otherwise, endless loop.

Comment: Also you should check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: But according to the text present in the file, `SG` is only in 3 lines right?

Comment: And you should `fclose` the file.

Comment: when should i close the file

Comment: @user8540390 you close it once you're done with it. Like when you exit a room, you shut down the light.

Comment: @user8540390 no SG is obviously present i 4 lines.. BTW the second comment is the answer

Comment: should also check the return value of `strtok` too

Comment: why is `while(strstr(a,"SG_")!=NULL)` an endless loop?

Comment: How does the while loop end if `a` never changes in the loop? If `strstr(a,"SG_")` succeeds once, it will succeed every time.  `strtok()` 
 may modify the string, but in this case that won't affect the condition. https://ideone.com/rFD2Mg

Comment: But now the file has `BA_ "GenMsgSendType" BO_ 356 0;
BA_ "GenMsgCycleTime" BO_ 356 100;
BA_ "GenMsgSendType" BO_ 358 0;` inside it, then strstr(a,"SG_") should fail atleast once right? when fgets reads line starting with BA_ instead of SG_

Comment: That's irrelevant. The first time it gets an "SG_" line it gets stuck in that loop. No more lines are read, so it never reaches the "BA_" lines.

Comment: How can I use strtok to replace the strstr and run the while loop.Thanks in advance

Comment: Or can I make a as NULL when it identifies other than SG_

Comment: Changing the `while` to `if` should work.